# post multideminsional array in multideminsional array

Tags: php, arrays

We need to post products here.

The product will have more than one color, while each color have different image.

I have created a form. in this form when user click `add more color`, it will create them a block div to pick up multiple images for that color, and so on for the next color.

Here is the sketch or input that I `will` create dynamically with js

```
//here is the master data
<input type="text" name="name"/>

//follows are the mapping data

<input type="text" name="color[red]" value="red" /> 
    <input type="file" name="color[red][image1]" /> 
    <input type="file" name="color[red][image2]" /> 
    <input type="file" name="color[red][image3]" /> 
    <input type="file" name="color[red][image4]" /> 

<input type="text" name="color[blue]" value="blue" />
    <input type="file" name="color[blue][image1]" /> 
    <input type="file" name="color[blue][image2]" /> 
    <input type="file" name="color[blue][image3]" /> 
    <input type="file" name="color[blue][image4]" /> 


    And so on...
```

I need a help how to post the inputs above with php, so that the output array would be like this:

```
array (
    name => one
    color => array (
                [0] => array (
                        name =>red
                        image => array (
                                    [0] =>oneRed1.jpg
                                    [1] =>oneRed2.jpg
                                    [2] =>oneRed3.jpg
                                 )  
                        )

                [1] => array (
                        name =>blue
                        image => array (
                                    [0] =>oneBlue1.jpg
                                    [1] =>oneBlue2.jpg
                                    [2] =>oneBlue3.jpg
                                 )  
                            )   
                [2] => array (
                        name =>purple
                        image => array (
                                    [0] =>onePurple1.jpg
                                    [1] =>onePurple2.jpg
                                    [2] =>onePurple3.jpg
                                 )  
                        )   
            )
    )
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? How is the form being submitted? Are you just using PHP to process this? No jQuery or Ajax?

Comment: This far no ajax. I am just thinking it will be easy to post this with php only. Ajax will make it more complicated, i guess.

Comment: So what have you tried thus far?

Comment: This far I am only able to post multiple images for one color. Now I need multiple color for multiple image inside it.

Comment: Where is the rest of the form code? Are you actually using `$_POST` to capture your form variables?

Comment: How does the button know what color to add next ?, So if i understand corretly, you have a list of colors (purple, blue, red etc).. and beside each colors theres a button that will add more variations to that color?
Why use images ? it would be easier to use another hex value as the variation ?

Comment: @the_pete I add a single input in the form. Yes, I am using `$_POST` or `(codeigniter = $this->input->post)`

Comment: Which are you using? `$_POST` or codeigniter to capture the form data? You also need to show us how you are capturing the data so we can help you create this array.

Comment: @obo,the color will have been prepared, they just need to choose from drop-down, and the name will be create base the value of the dropdown. If user need to add new color  which has not been exist yet, then they will post it in the color category first.

Comment: @the_pete I would prefer to use $_POST for file input

Comment: Okay, where's the code where you are capturing the form values?

Comment: You mean for capturing the form value are `$name = $_POST["name"];` , `$color=$_POST["color"]` & `$image=$_POST['image']` ?

Comment: I need a help to capture the form value for the color and image.

Comment: Anybody needs my update code?